# How to extract all ancestors from family predicate?

Tags: prolog

I have these given facts in format `family(parent1, parent2, listOfChildren)`:

```
family (1,2,[9,10]).
family (1,3,[11]).
family (4,5,[12,13,14]).
family (6,7,[8]).
family (8,9,[15]).
family (11,13,[16]).
```

I need to extract all ancestors of given child.
For example

```
 ancestors(16,L)
```

should 'return': [11,13,1,3,4,5]

I'm struggling with this a few days. Your help would be 'a savior'.

Comment: Struggling suggests you've been actively trying to solve this, and to do so for days means you must have tried a few things. What have you tried?

Comment: ancestor(X,L):-findall([A,B],(family(A,B,C),memberchk(X,C)),L). So, I extract the parents, but, I can not continue with grandparents, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should first concentrate on writing a predicate that succeeds when the first argument is an ancestor of the second. So, `ancestor(X,Z)` like this:

```
ancestor(X,Z) :- family(X,_,Zs), member(Z,Zs).
ancestor(Y,Z) :- family(_,Y,Zs), member(Z,Zs).

ancestor(X,Z) :- family(W,_,Zs), member(Z,Zs), ancestor(X,W).
ancestor(Y,Z) :- family(_,W,Zs), member(Z,Zs), ancestor(Y,W).
```

Now, `findall` is useful.

```
?- findall(X,ancestor(X,_),Xs), list_to_set(Xs,Ys), write(Ys)
```

I used `list_to_set/1` to remove duplicates.

That produces:

```
[1,4,6,8,11,2,3,5,7,9,13]
```

Now, I can do this query:

```
?- ancestor(L,16).
L = 11 .
```

Note that I swapped the ordering of the arguments you gave as Prolog is usually read in this way: "***L*** is an ***ancestor*** of ***16***"

Comment: This gave me an idea. The problem is solved. Thank you !

Comment: @Vladimir99 - Can you please upvote and accept? Or post your own answer and accept that?

Comment: Sorry that I forget to accept, now it's done. But I can't upvote, because of my reputation.